# systemd-resolved jammed after kubuntu upgrade to 22.04.01 LTS

Tags: networking, upgrade, kubuntu, dns

After upgrading Kubuntu 20.04.03 LTS to 22.04.01 LTS, I must bring up DNS manually in a Konsole.

```
:~$ resolvectl status
Failed to get global data: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.resolve1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)

:~$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved

:~$ resolvectl status
Global
Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp11s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 10.0.2.1
       DNS Servers: 10.0.2.1
        DNS Domain: NetZ
```

This is the only way I have found so far to get DNS up.
How might I track down what has changed?

Answer (score 1):

Kubuntu 22.04.01 is not entirely compatible with a MacPro Late 2013 (Trash Can).  Multiple (3-6) systemd services time out on boot leading to long boot times and resolved service failing.
The fix for me was the 22.04.2 update. Now everything seems to work like 20.04.3 or better.